# Core Data error: Failed to load model, 'An NSManagedObject of class 'MyApp.Item' must have a valid NSEntityDescription

Tags: swift, core-data

I created a Swift project with no coredata, only to add some later. I copied the following code from a real template to my project AppDelegate and created my coredata model file. However, As soon as I created a coreData object using the context, I got:

> CoreData: error:  Failed to load model named coredatatemplate

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'MyApp.Item' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.

I had to look around to figure out the problem, as I already had done the following:

- My custom entity had the same Class name and Entity name that matched the coredata file
- I had selected `Current Product Module` for `Module`
- I had selected the standard `Class Definition` for `Codegen`

(Check to make sure these are alright if you're having the same problem.)

[image]

The problem persisted and I couldn't find the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **SOLUTION:**

What was wrong in my case is that the template code used another name than my CoreData file.

In my AppDelegate:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Using `name: "DataModel"`, which I had to change to match `DataModel.xcdatamodeld` in my project.